# Is it possible to enable a form for entering bearer tokens in Swagger-UI from ServiceStack's OpenApiFeature?

Tags: servicestack, swagger-ui, bearer-token, openapi

Is it possible to enable a form for entering bearer tokens in Swagger-UI from ServiceStack's OpenApiFeature? This is possible in NSwag with their Swagger 2.0 implementation.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Support for being able to customize Security Definitions was added in [this commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/commit/d5c478f92c7db7d378bc6285a17dd327df4408bd) where you can specify that you want "Bearer" Api Key authentication with:

```
Plugins.Add(new OpenApiFeature
{
    UseBearerSecurity = true,
});
```

> If you want to revert to using HTTP Basic Auth Security use `UseBasicSecurity=true`

This will customize the Open API metadata Response to specify your authenticated Services would like to use Swagger's API Key authentication, e.g:

[image]

As the **value** field is for the entire `Authorization` HTTP Header you'd need to add your JWT Token or API Key prefixed with `Bearer`:

```
Bearer {JWT or API Key}
```

This change is available from the latest v5.4.1 on MyGet, if you already have v5.4.1 installed you will need to [clear your NuGet packages cache](https://docs.servicestack.net/myget#redownloading-myget-packages).

Comment: Seeing an error with the `ServiceStack.Api.OpenApi.Core` package:

```warn: ServiceStack.Host.Handlers.StaticFileHandler[0]
      Static File '/swaggerui/' not found in path: /swagger-ui/```

Should I report a bug somewhere?

Comment: @yenta I'm unable to repro it, but there shouldn't be any requests to `/swaggerui/`  anywhere, the path to Swagger UI is `/swagger-ui/`, you can also click on the "Swagger UI" link in your metadata page.

Comment: the only difference i can find between 5.4.0 and 5.4.1 of `ServiceStack.Api.OpenApi.Core` is that the embedded resources in 5.4.0 have a prefix of `ServiceStack.Api.OpenApi` while the ones in 5.4.1 have a prefix of `ServiceStack.Api.OpenApi.Core` and that seems to be messing up the virtualfilehandler since the nameof(backingAssembly) is `ServiceStack.Api.OpenApi`

Comment: @yenta ok thx, this was due to moving to the [new build system](https://forums.servicestack.net/t/v5-4-1-now-hosting-source-link-enabled-packages/6728), I've just added `<RootNamespace>` to all .Core.csproj's which now maintains embedded resources under the `ServiceStack.Api.OpenApi` namespace which is now available from the latest v5.4.1 on MyGet, as you already had v5.4.1 installed you'll need to [clear your NuGet packages cache](https://docs.servicestack.net/myget#redownloading-myget-packages).

Comment: Thanks, SwaggerUI works again and the Bearer Security feature also works nicely.

Comment: @mythz How to configure swagger UI to use bearer token authentication in V5.0?